# Dynamically load a Ruby container in Docker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, docker

I'm setting up a Dockerfile for my Rails project. To do so, I'm loading the Ruby Docker container like this:

```
FROM ruby:2.2.3
```

My application already contains a .ruby-version file that's used everywhere else to set the version. I'd really love to avoid duplicating the version number in my Dockerfile. Essentially, I'd like to do something like this:

```
Ruby ruby:$(cat .ruby-verison)
```

The above command doesn't work. Is there some other way of accomplishing the same thing with Docker?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [RVM](https://rvm.io/) to accomplish this.  It doesn't matter what docker image you use as long as it has `rvm` installed on it.  Here is an example Dockerfile:

```
 FROM yograterol:fedora-rvm
 ADD 'your_script.sh' '/'
 ADD '.ruby-version' '/'
 RUN 'sh /your_script.sh'
```

And here is what `your_script.sh` could look like:

```
 ruby_version=$(cat .ruby-version)
 rvm install ruby-$ruby_version
 rvm use ruby-$ruby_version
```